# Totally geodesic submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading "Introduction to symplectic topology", D.McDuff, D.Salamonand and I have a problem with the exercise 1.26. According to the definition, a submanifold $L$ of a Riemannian manifold $(\mathbb R^n,g)$ is called totally geodesic if $\nabla\dot{x}(s)\in T_{x(s)}L$ for every smooth curve $x(s)\in L$. It is necessary to prove that if $L$ is totally geodesic then any geodesic on $L$ is also geodesic in $\mathbb R^n$.

Consider $L=\mathbb R^1\subset\mathbb R^2$ and the Riemannian metric
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\arctan(x_1+x_2)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\arctan(x_1+x_2)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{\arctan(x_1+x_2)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $$\Gamma_{11}^2(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(g^{21}\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x_1}+g^{22}\left(2\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{x_2}\right)\right)=0.$$ If $x(s)=(x_1(s),0)\in L$ then $$(\nabla\dot{x})_2=\ddot{x}_2+\sum_{i,j=1}^2\Gamma_{ij}^2(x)\dot{x}_i\dot{x}_j=\Gamma_{11}^2\dot{x}_1^2=0,$$ thus $L$ is totally geodesic. Suppose that $x(s)=(x_1(s),0)$ is geodesic on $L$. It means that $x_1(s)$ satisfies the equation $$\ddot{x}_1+\bar\Gamma_{11}^1\dot{x}_1^2=0,\tag 1$$ where $\bar\Gamma_{11}^1$ is the Christoffel symbol for the induced Riemannian metric $\bar g(x_1)=g_{11}(x_1,0)$ on $L$. In this case $$\bar\Gamma_{11}^1(x_1)=\frac{1}{2}g^{11}(x_1,0)\frac{\partial g_{11}(x_1,0)}{\partial x_1}$$ and (1) takes the form $$\ddot{x}_1+\frac{1}{2}g^{11}(x_1,0)\frac{\partial g_{11}(x_1,0)}{\partial x_1}\dot{x}_1^2=0\tag 2$$ The statement of this exercise implies that $x(s)$ is also geodesic in $\mathbb R^2$ so $x_1(s)$ satisfies the equation $$\ddot{x}_1+\Gamma_{11}^1(x_1,0)\dot{x}_1^2=0,\tag 3$$ $$\Gamma_{11}^1=\frac{1}{2}\left(g^{11}\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial x_1}+g^{12}\left(2\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{x_2}\right)\right).\tag 4$$ The equalities (2),(3) and (4) give us $$g^{12}\left(2\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{x_2}\right)\dot{x}_1^2=0,$$ but $$g^{12}\left(2\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial g_{11}}{x_2}\right)=\frac{2}{(2\arctan(x_1)-\pi)(x_1^2+1)}\ne 0.$$ We finally obtain that $x(s)=(x_1(s),0)$ is not geodesic in $\mathbb R^2$ even if $x_1(s)$ is geodesic on $L$. I wonder if the condition of the problem is correct and where is my mistake? Thanks for helping.

Comment: The second fundamental form is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\nabla \dot{x}(s)\in T_{x(s)}L$ implies that $\nabla\dot{x}(s)=\tilde{\nabla}\dot{x}(s)$, where $\tilde{\nabla}$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $L$. Now, if $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $L$, then$$\nabla\dot{\gamma}=\tilde{\nabla}\dot{\gamma}=0,$$and hence $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $\mathbb{R}^n$ too.

Comment: Thanks helpful explanation. I understood my mistake: the Christoffel symbol for L is calculated incorrectly.